# How to get NON - logged in users to the site to see the freeform:edit tag?

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace

I am submitting a form and that form will email a client at the supplied email address. However, in the email that is sent to the client a URL is included to edit their response. On this page I am using the freeform:edit tag but they can not see it because they are not logged in.

Example URL:
sitegoeshere.com/refferal/mma/26/1-23456789

Segment 3 would be the freeform entry id but if they are not logged in the client can not see this.

**So any ideas on how to make a non-logged in user edit an entry?**

I know the security risk of anyone can see any entry but none of the data is worth anything to someone else.

- Eric

Answer (score 2):

Just add `restrict_edit_to_author="no"` to your `freeform:edit` tag. From the [docs](https://solspace.com/docs/freeform/edit/#restrict_edit_to_author):

> Specifying a value of no to this parameter will mean that anyone, including logged out users / guests can edit the entry.